# how to detect a table is created or skipped in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I create a table and an index for that in Postgres by python. I want skip creating an index when creating the table skipped.
how to detect a table is created or skipped in Postgres?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_one () INHERITS (table)
```

if creating table isn't skipped

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_one USING btree (id, time_stamp)
```

Comment: What about adding `IF NOT EXISTS table_one` on the end of the `CREATE INDEX...` and moving it up so that it's before the create table call?

Comment: is it possible to create an index before creating table?! create index on what?

Comment: @jam3: there is no `create index if not exists` in the current version of Postgres. The upcoming 9.5 will have it though.

Comment: The other way would be to add a name for the index to the `create index` command. (using a/the default name) This would cause an *object exists* error if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an anonymous block?

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE table_one () INHERITS (table);
    CREATE INDEX ON table_one USING btree (id, time_stamp);
EXCEPTION   
    WHEN duplicate_table THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table already exists, ignoring...';
END$$;
```